# Firefox & IE agree with each other (but not Chrome) on rendering padding for element with display: table-cell

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome

I'm trying to create a site which uses laterally-stacked "blades" of content. The element containing them is moved laterally inside a div with `overflow-x: hidden` to create the desired sidescrolling effect. This seems to be working fine: The element containing the "blades" is set to `display: table; width: 100%; table-layout: fixed` and each blade is styled as follows: `display: table-cell; width: 601px; border-right: 1px solid white; padding: 10px`. Finally, the nav element has width 621px, with no horizontal padding or margins.

It all seems simple enough, but I'm getting a very odd cross-browser bug: Firefox and IE9 agree on how the page looks, but Chrome has a different opinion. I've figured out *what* Chrome is doing, but I haven't been able to figure out *why* it's doing it.

The doctype's set and everything else seems to be working fine. Except for background-colors, the rules above are all I've defined in the stylesheet, and there are no inline styles. Here are some screenshots which illustrate the problem behavior.

[image: The page in Firefox]

Here's the page in Firefox - as desired, the right edge of the navigation bar aligns with the right edge of the content box.

[image: The page in IE9]

Same in IE9.

[image: The page in Chrome]

In Chrome, the padding is subtracted from the width, creating the overhang shown above. I never set `border-box` anywhere in the stylesheet, nor do I see it in the computed rules in Chrome - it just says that the width is 581px, whereas it's 601px in the other two browsers.

[Note: I saw that there were other posts on padding issues, but none where Firefox and IE9 agreed and Chrome did something different.]

**Edit** Here's a JSFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/aCeAw/

Comment: Without a link or a jsfiddle, we can only take wild guesses.

Comment: JSFiddle link added; each browser renders the fiddle the same as in the screenshots above.

Comment: Are you currently using a CSS reset?

Comment: The fiddle renders differently for me in (ubuntu) firefox nightly and stable, specifically the div.blade-viewer.home current changes in size with screen resizes at a different rate than the navigation bar. 
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/12468262/test.html
This seems to render differently than you described, can you confirm the differences?
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/12468262/ehdv_chrome.png
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/12468262/ehdv_ff.png

Comment: That looks unfortunately like a bug in Firefox; the width of the navigation is currently an exact pixel width (621px), and the contained `ul` element is set to `width: 100%` to fill the space. Can you check to see if the nav's width rule is still being applied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a bug in Chrome.  When it computes column widths for `table-layout: fixed`, it incorrectly ignores cell padding.  See discussion in https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=652941 complete with spec quotes, and the almost-5-year-old WebKit bug report at https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=13339.

You may be able to work around this by using width styles on `display: table-column` elements, as discussed in the Mozilla bug report above.  Alternately, you could add a first row with 0 height and no paddings, but the cell widths you want...  I realize both of those mess with the actual site markup, which may not be an option in your case, of course.